# dplyr with do assignments duplicate first value

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to assign a variable to the `.` data frame from but `dplyr` seems to do some magic behind the scenes that I don't understand. What is the proper way of performing the following:

```
data_frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
  var = c(1:6)
) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  do({
    .$var = rep(max(.$var), times = nrow(.))
    .
  })
```

In it's current format it gives:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   id [1]
     id   var
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     2
3     1     2
4     1     2
5     1     2
6     1     2
```

I can get around it assigning the `.` to a new variable but this seems like a hack:

```
data_frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
  var = c(1:6)
) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  do({
    alt = as_data_frame(.)
    alt$var = rep(max(alt$var), times = nrow(alt))
    alt
  })
```

Gives the expected result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
     id   var
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     2
3     2     4
4     2     4
5     3     6
6     3     6
```

## Complex example

By popular demand - here's an example more like what I'm trying to do. In short it's a form of imputation where it looks if there is a missing value in a series where:

1. if the value before and after are the same then it is assumed that the value the same as the surrounding values.
2. This assumption is only valid if a second variable indicates that less than a certain time has passed between the two time points.
3. It also checks so that the missing value isn't the first or the last in the particular set.
4. There may also be multiple missing values and therefore it tries to loop through each value.
5. Surrounding values cannot be missing

The code is:

```
data_frame(
  id = rep(1:5, each=3),
  var = c(
    'a', NA, 'a', 
    'b', NA, 'a',
    'b', NA, 'b',
    'a', 'b', 'b',
    NA, 'b', 'b'
  ),
  time = c(
    0, 1, 10, 
    0, 1, 10,
    0, 1, 20,
    0, 1, 10,
    0, 1, 10)
) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  do({
    for (i in which(is.na(.$var))) {
      if (i > 1 &&
          i < nrow(.) &&
          !is.na(.$var[i-1]) &&
          !is.na(.$var[i+1]) &&
          .$var[i-1] == .$var[i+1] &&
          (.$time[i+1] - .$time[i-1]) < 14) {
        .$var[i] = .$var[i+1]
      }
    }
    .
  })
```

The same hack seems to do the job:

```
  ...
  do({
    retData <- as_data_frame(.)
    for (i in which(is.na(.$var))) {
      if (i > 1 &&
          i < nrow(.) &&
          !is.na(.$var[i-1]) &&
          !is.na(.$var[i+1]) &&
          .$var[i-1] == .$var[i+1] &&
          (.$time[i+1] - .$time[i-1]) < 14) {
        retData$var[i] = .$var[i+1]
      }
    }
    retData
  })
```

With the proper replacements:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   id [5]
      id   var  time
   <int> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1     a     0
 2     1     a     1
 3     1     a    10
 4     2     b     0
 5     2  <NA>     1
 6     2     a    10
 7     3     b     0
 8     3  <NA>     1
 9     3     b    20
10     4     a     0
11     4     b     1
12     4     b    10
13     5  <NA>     0
14     5     b     1
15     5     b    10
```

Comment: `group_by(id) %>% mutate(var = max(var))`?

Comment: Thanks @Nate but the actual `do`-loop is much more complicated so `mutate` doesn't work. I've simplified the example for making it easier to grasp

Comment: so what are the extra things that `do` is doing? if you need multiple operations on `var`,  `mutate` can handle that

Comment: @Nate - it's my own personal nightmare but I'll share it so at least someone may get a good laugh: it's a form of imputation where it looks if there is a missing value in a series, if the value before and after are the same then it is assumed that the value is accurate. This assumption is only valid if a second variable indicates that less than a year has passed between the two time points. It also checks so that the missing value isn't the first or the last in the particular set. There may also be multiple missing values and therefore it tries to loop through each value.

Comment: @Henrik - added a complex example to better illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Henrik yeah, it's a tricky. The time between the two surrounding values have to be less than 14 in this example. This is why I skipped it in the original version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited to deal with complicated case**

I think it's easier to simply find the row-index of observations that need editing. You can use `dplyr::lead/lag` functions to help you here.

```
library(dplyr)
posindex <- which(is.na(df$var) &                    # is na
                  lag(df$id) == lead(df$id) &        # is -1 and +1 id the same?
                  lag(df$var) == lead(df$var) &      # is -1 and +1 var the same? 
                  (lead(df$time) - lag(df$time)) < 14)  # is +1 minus -1 time < 14?
# Output: 2

df$var[posindex] <- df$var[(posindex+1)]
   # id  var time
# 1   1    a    0
# 2   1    a    1
# 3   1    a   10
# 4   2    b    0
# 5   2 <NA>    1
# 6   2    a   10
# 7   3    b    0
# 8   3 <NA>    1
# 9   3    b   20
# 10  4    a    0
# 11  4    b    1
# 12  4    b   10
# 13  5 <NA>    0
# 14  5    b    1
# 15  5    b   10
```

Comment: looks interesting but I just don't get it - can you get the complex example to work like this?

Comment: thanks! While this is an elegant solution that I'll use, I'm still a little confused by the original behavior - is that a pointer bug in dplyr that should be reported or did I miss something in how `do` operates?

Comment: I think this is an issue that has come up before and been logged with the developers as a "bug". See [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2970).